# Double affiliation: is it understood as simultaneous part-time in each of them?

Tags: affiliation

If I write a double affiliation, would it be understood as

1. I'm in both institutes
2. I was in one institute and I am working for the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many interpretations for dual affiliations. You must explicitly provide an interpretation, if required. You could do so in a footnote on the first page or in the acknowledgements, for example.

Comment: If the work was only done with a previous, outdated affiliation, some journals (e.g. Science) offer another footnote with "current adress: xyz". If you continued working on the project at a second institute, or generally have two affiliations (e.g. university and non-university research facilities), then you just state them as both and let the reader interpret it. In that case, it is often not clarified further.

Comment: @BPND I always list my current affiliation, not my previous affiliation (because I'm no longer affiliated with it), and mention my previous affiliation in the acknowledgements if necessary (e.g., to acknowledge financial support).

Comment: @BPND Regarding non-university research facilities, authors should check whether listing the affiliation is permitted by the facility, authors may also need to follow the facility's publication procedure (which may, for instance, include granting permission to publish).

Answer (score 1):

There are various options for double-affiliation. I think, the part-time is the least frequent in my view. I would say that probably the most frequent one is when a researcher moves from one institution to another.  In general, in the paper you usually use affiliation of the institution where the work was actually done, regardless of where you are now. So, if since then you moved to another institution, people also might want to put their new affiliation.